# HREF values search through the web page using BS4

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am working on 3rd Party application where I have read view to the Webpage source content.And from there we have to collect only some `href` content values which has pattern like `/aems/file/filegetrevision.do?fileEntityId`. Is it possible? My one giving me all the `href` values.

***HTML*** **(Part of HTML)**

```
<td width="50%">
<a href="/aems/file/filegetrevision.do?fileEntityId=10597525&cs=9b7sjueBiWLBEMj2ZU4I6fyQoPv-g0NLY9ETqP0gWk4.xyz">
screenshot.doc
</a>
</td>
```

**CODE**

```
for a in soup.find_all('a', {"style": "display:inline; position:relative;"}, href=True):
    href = a['href'].strip()
    href = "https://xyz.test.com/" + href
print(href)
```

Thanks

Thanks,

Comment: @CRUSADER Yes I have tried, but not worked. For you find above!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, just use a proper filter for the `href` attribute. Like

```
def filter(href):
    return '/aems/file/filegetrevision' in href

soup.find_all('a', href=filter)
```

Besides functions, you can also use `RegexObject` objects as filters:

```
filter = re.compile(some_regular_expression)
soup.find_all('a', href=filter)
```

See the docs: [Kind of filters](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#kinds-of-filters)

Comment: I'd probably use `href.startswith('...')` in this case. And shouldn't the regex example be `re.compile('...').match` or alternatively `partial(re.match, '...')` ?

Comment: @JonClements No need for that, BS groks `RegexObject`s just as well as callables. +1 for `startswith` though, I'm not sure what filter exactly the OP wants but it will probably be handy.

Comment: You're right (for some reason I thought it didn't do that - I'm possibly confusing it with another library) - `If you pass in a regular expression object, Beautiful Soup will filter against that regular expression using its match() method.` (might be worth adding that to your answer for clarity) - anyway +1.

Comment: @Kos I want to take out all `href` values from the webpage based on the patteren `/aems/file/filegetrevision.do?fileEntityId`. I thought you got it properly as you mentioned in your answer. :)

Comment: @VBSlover If all urls start with that, then using `href.startswith(pattern)` like @JonClements suggested will be faster than `pattern in href`, if that makes a difference.

Comment: See there are several `<a>` but i am interested only to that pattern to get collect as those i need to download from the webpage.